# Swift: UICollectionView + Custom Segue makes problems

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, segue

In the following application, I am using an UICollectionView. The text of each cell (string) is downloaded from my SQL-Server. This works pretty well. But somehow, my app sometimes looks as it should, but sometimes not (this happens in simulator, as well as on a native device).
I guess it has something to do with the custom segue I am using, when clicking the settings button (down-right).

```
@IBAction func settingsButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // in order to prevent an exception, you have to add an Identity in Main.storyboard
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

    // instantiate view controller by storyboard
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsViewController") as! SettingsViewController

    // custom segue
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueToRight", sender: sender)

    // pass email
    nextViewController.email = self.email

    // switch view controller
    self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
}
```

**Displayed right:**
[image]

**Displayed wrong:**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably caused because **you are using two different** presentation methods, a `segue` and a `present`.

Try to remove `self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)` since the `performSegue` function will handle the transition for you already.

Also, `nextViewController.email = self.email` should be set **before** `performSegue` to ensure that the data will be passed to the next controller properly.

**UPDATE FOR COMMENTS**

You need to split your code in two. Inside the `@IBAction` invoke the `performSegue` call:

```
@IBAction func settingsButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // custom segue
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueToRight", sender: sender)
}
```

Then **override** `prepareForSegue:sender:`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let nextViewController = segue.destination as! SettingsViewController
    nextViewController.email = self.email
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! The animation now works properly. But now I have the problem that my email is not transmitted correctly (because ViewController is not switched). Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: did you changed the `nextViewController.email = self.email` as I suggested?

Comment: yes, it's now before the performSegue function-call

Comment: right, you need to split your code in two, I will update my answer, and please, since I already answered your original question please accept it :)

Comment: Sorry for my inattention, I forgot it :D

Comment: thank you, for your answer! Now the animation works. But the problem with the all-black-screen didn't disappear. I ran the app and it worked fine. Than I ran it again, without change **anything** and the screen problem I described above, appeared again. Sometimes it works, sometimes not (without changing anything). I don't get that :/

Comment: You might have another problem regarding your storyboard or the destination view controller. Review constraints and `viewDidLoad` methods and in case you don't figure out submit another questions.

Comment: that's the viewDidLoad()-function from the HomeViewController (pictures above). Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJ2Ia.png

Comment: In the function, I download some text from my database (via php-interface) and format it to my needs.

Comment: can you share your storyboard?

Comment: Thanks for you efforts. But I think, I have already found a solution. I always have to look up, if the storyboard is built (headline). Then it works fine. :)

Comment: I am glad! Check your project main storyboard config, that could help too.

Comment: I am glad too. Thanks, you helped me a lot. :)